Combined Forward and Backward Euler Method for Solving Second Order ODEs
Suppose I want to solve a second order system numerically using fixed, discrete timesteps.
$$y'' = f(y,y',t)$$
A simple and common solution would be to split the system into two first-order ODEs and solve them separately using the Euler-Forward method:
$$y'[k+1] = y'[k] + hf(y[k],y'[k],t_k) \\ y[k+1] = y[k] + hy'[k]$$
My question is why, if we calculate $y'[k+1]$ first, not use this result and calcualte $y[k+1]$ using the Backward-Euler formula, since it seems to be more stable:
$$y'[k+1] = y'[k] + hf(y[k],y'[k],t_k) \quad \textrm{(Same as above)} \\ y[k+1] = y[k] + hy'[\mathbf{k+1}]$$
I could not find any reference to this technique being used anywhere, maybe someone can point me to a possible reference. It could also be that this is a bad idea and I haven't realized yet why, so if this is the case any details to why would be appreciated.

You can check out semi-implicit Euler method. In a similar vein you can look at Verlet or leapfrog integrators. Higher order generalisation for Hamiltonian systems are symplectic integrators (this should give you a couple of keywords at least).

@LPZ Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. It's hard to search for things if you don't know how they are called. If you repost your comment as an answer I can mark it as such.
